# FillRect multiple times

Tags: java, graphics, paintcomponent

The fillRect-Method is only working for the first "fillRect" in line 6.But not for the second "fillRect".What can i do about this?

```
public class VertikalerStrich extends JLabel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics vs){
        int x=240;
        int y=460;

        vs.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        vs.fillRect(x, y, 20, 100);
        y = y+100;
        vs.fillRect(x, y, 20, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the current size of your component at the time of the drawings?

Comment: @Jean-Bptiste Yunes 600x600

Comment: Please use the code tool when pasting code

Comment: @BackSlash Havent I used the code tool?Sorry I am new to this platform.

Comment: @Tubinator seriously? I doubt your label has size 600x600... make a fillRect with getSize()  and you will see...

Comment: @Tubinator No, you used the blockquote tool. To use the code tool you need to click on the `{}` icon above the editor

Comment: Can you explain it to me?What should it help when i know the size of my component?The first fillRect is working perfectly.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès Can you explain it to me?What should it help when i know the size of my component?The first fillRect is working perfectly

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working". What are you expecting, and what do you get that doesn't meet your expectations? Also it seems to me that two calls are not necessary - one with a height of 200 would do the same.

Comment: @Tubinator it may happen that your component do not have the size you think...